# using aggregation MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregate, mongo-shell

I'm trying to use .aggregate() with other mongo shell methods and i got
**UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: User.find(...).select(...).sort(...).aggregate is not a function**

```
const users = await User
            .find(findParams)
            .select(userResponse)
            .sort(sortParams)
            .aggregate(([
                {
                    $project:{
                        dateCreated: {$dateToString: {format: "%G-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", date: "$dateCreated"}},
                    }
                }
            ]))
            .exec()
```

BUT, when i use .aggregate() without other methods it works perfect.

```
const users = await User
            .aggregate(([
                {
                    $project:{
                        dateCreated: {$dateToString: {format: "%G-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", date: "$dateCreated"}},
                    }
                }
            ]))
            .exec()
```

Can i insert it with other methods but without getting this error.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first block of code, you are trying to apply db.collection.aggregate() method on a cursor which is returned by find() method. Cursors are which basically returned from collection methods like find(), aggregate() and [more here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/js-collection/).

In the second code block, you are directly applying aggregate() on the *User* collection. That's why it is working. And yes, you can do whatever select, sort, limit using aggregate() even without using those cursor methods [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/js-cursor/). Hope this will help, Dude. Have a great day!

[MongoDB documentation page screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrEd2.png)